# Get an XML Element's Attribute a Property when Deserializing .NET

Tags: c#, xml, vb.net, serialization, nested-attributes

I have searched extensively to find this answer, and I do not think it's possible, but I figured I would ask.  This would be relevant to VB and C# users as well.

I have an XML (that looks to have been serialized) from another application.  I currently have created lots of classes that mimic the structure of the XML, and everything works fine.  However, I am using the Top level class structure in my own application to access properties from this later using Reflection and Dictionaries.

This has created several cases where I have to dig through layers of class objects to get to the value I want.  In many cases, the value is simply an attribute of an element; in multiple cases, right at the top level of the XML.  My question is, can I access, with De-Serialization, that Element's Attribute at the top level class?  Without the need to create a nested / child class that captures them?

Again, this all works with a complex class structure, I'm just trying to simplify things for later use.  This is an extremely simple example below, but these cases are all over the XML files I am working with.

Here is a simple example of the XML I am trying to deserialize

```
<ParentClass name="Jeremy" role="engineer">
    <ChildClass total="10" />
</ParentClass>
```

Here is the class structure I know I can use today.  However, to access the value Total, I would have to call it with User.Points.Total

```
<Serializable> <XmlRoot("ParentClass")> Public Class User
    <XmlAttribute("name")> Public Property UserName as String
    <XmlAttribute("role")> Public Property UserRole as String
    <XmlElement("ChildClass")> Public Property Points as Points
End Class

<Serializable> Public Class Points
    <XmlAttribute("total")> Public Property Total as String
End Class
```

What am hoping is possible, is something like the following, where I can more easily call User.Total.

Notice I called it XmlMagicalFlag in this case.

```
<Serializable> <XmlRoot("ParentClass")> Public Class User
    <XmlAttribute("name")> Public Property UserName as String
    <XmlAttribute("role")> Public Property UserRole as String
    <XmlMagicalFlag("total")> Public Property Total as String
End Class
```

Answer (score -1):

For simplicity and further convenient work, i recommend you to use xsd-generating utility [xsd.exe](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x6c1kb0s(v=vs.110).aspx).

It is usually located at: **C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\\Bin**, if you have an installed SDK.

For example, we have an xml-file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<ParentClass name="Jeremy" role="engineer">
    <ChildClass total="10" />
</ParentClass>
```

Using command line, lets generate a schema:

***C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\Bin>xsd.exe C:\Docs\test.xml***

As the result, now we have an xsd file **test.xsd**.

At next step we create class structure from xsd file:

***C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\Bin>xsd.exe test.xsd /classes***

After that, as a result, you have autogenerated classes, with annotations, ready to serialize/deserialize, like:

```
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", 2.0.50727.3038")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType=true)]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace="", IsNullable=false)]
public partial class ParentClass {

    private ParentClassChildClass[] childClassField;

    private string nameField;

    private string roleField;

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("ChildClass",Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
    public ParentClassChildClass[] ChildClass {
        get {
            return this.childClassField;
        }
        set {
            this.childClassField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public string name {
        get {
            return this.nameField;
        }
        set {
            this.nameField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public string role {
        get {
            return this.roleField;
        }
        set {
            this.roleField = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Since that, you can deserialize your xml-file, and do everything you want:

```
public static ParentClass Deserialize(Stream dictFileStream, XmlSerializer serializer)
{
    var reader = XmlReader.Create(dictFileStream);
    var item = (ParentClass)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
    return item;
}
```

usage:

```
using (var file = new FileStream(@"c:\Docs\test.xml", FileMode.Open))
{
    var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ParentClass));
    var parent = Deserialize(file, serializer);

    // do what you want
    parent.name = ...
    parent.ChildClass.total ...
}
```

Comment: I don't see where this solves for the attribute total in the parent class?  This looks like what I am already capable of doing using the xmlserializer?

Comment: I don't listed the generated ChildClass code here, for shortness, only ParentClass. But i think from my example it should be clear.This utility will generate all needed entities from your xml-file, if it has correct structure. And after generation, add this generated entities to your project, and work through XmlSerializer.